# In React Three Fiber, children don't move with the parent

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using React Three Fiber. I have a group, and within that group, I have a green cube. On the mesh onClick event, I create a child cube. On the group's onDoubleClick event, I intend to move the green cube, with the expectation that the green cube will move with all of the group's child cubes. However, only the green cube moves.

I attempted to use the updateMatrixWorld function, but it doesn't seem to work either. I have created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-banzai-28yy95?file=/src/App.js:1206-1223) to demonstrate the issue.

```
 import './styles.css'
import React, { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useMemo, Suspense, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react'
import { Box3, Vector3 } from 'three'
import { useLoader, Canvas, useThree, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Box } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'

function Scene() {
  const [childCubes, setChildCubes] = useState([])
  //const [isAddingChildCube, setIsAddingChildCube] = useState(false);

  // Add a child cube to the scene
  const addChildCube = () => {
    const newChild = {
      position: [
        Math.random() * 4 - 2, // Random X position
        Math.random() * 4 - 2, // Random Y position
        Math.random() * 4 - 2 // Random Z position
      ]
    }
    setChildCubes([...childCubes, newChild])
  }

  // Create an array of child cube components
  const childCubeComponents = childCubes.map((child, index) => (
    <Box key={index} position={child.position} args={[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]} color="red" />
  ))

  const moveAll = (event) => {
    const [x, y, z] = event.point.toArray()
    const newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, 0.5)
    event.object.position.copy(newPosition)
    event.object.updateMatrixWorld()
  }

  return (
    <group onDoubleClick={moveAll}>
      {/* Render child cube components */}
      {childCubeComponents}

      {/* Clickable 3D Cube as a Button */}
      <mesh
        position={[0, 0, 0]} // Adjust the position as needed
        onClick={addChildCube} // Trigger the addition of child cubes
      >
        <boxGeometry attach="geometry" args={[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="green" />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }}>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 5] }}>
        <ambientLight />
        <pointLight position={[3, 3, 3]} />
        <Scene />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: The event.object is probably the green cube itself, but you probably want to move the group. Check what the event.object is.. also maybe check the event.object for a reference to the group.. maybe event.object.parent or something like that. (I am not sure, never used react three fibre)